# send multiple messages to single device in one shot in GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

As we can send one message to multiple device, in the same way 
Can we send multiple suppose 10 message to single device at the same time (in one shot) in GCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. A request sent to the GCM server can have multiple registration IDs, but only one payload.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also  want to know can we send same message multiple times to same device in one shot?

Comment: @PPD That would make no sense. You can try sending the same registration ID multiple times. I don't know if the GCM server would accept it and actually try to deliver multiple messages to the same device.

Comment: Yes it makes no sense, I just want to know for curiosity. Thanks